# react native - screen cut off at bottom

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm building a React Native app for the first time using an iOS Simulator with XCode, and it seems that my elements on the bottom of the screen are being cut off, as if the screen can only scroll so far. I've tried changing the overall container `View`'s height, but it doesn't change how far down I can scroll. I've also tried removing the styling, as well as changing `View` to `ScrollView`, but neither helped. Another strange thing is that I need to add `paddingTop`, otherwise, the first `Text` is displayed over the time in the simulator

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Fields from './components/Fields.js'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Calculator</Text>
        <Text>1099 Calculator</Text>
        <Fields />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 50
  },
});
```

Here's the top of the screen without the padding
[image]

And here's how it looks cut off
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is an issue I also had. To fix it just wrap your container with another view without padding but with flex. So like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Calculator</Text>
          <Text>1099 Calculator</Text>
          <Fields />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 50
  },
  main: {
   flex: 1   
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's still being cut off. Nothing's changed.

Comment: Ah, this lets me CLICK and MOVE the mouse to scroll down the inner view, whereas I was only scrolling on the trackpad. Now it shows everything!

Comment: @paoliff this was the topic that helped me - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3422 - maybe try setting `height: 100%` on the `main` as well.

Comment: Hi @paoliff if my answer helped you, please up vote or accept it. Thank you! :)

Comment: The method in this comment solved it for me.  (Now I have a view with flex:1, wrapping a ScrollView with contentContainerStyle flexGrow:1, wrapping another view with flex:1) https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3422#issuecomment-334706789

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, it turned out to be the padding that I added to my ScrollView. Maybe it is not the solution, it is simply to discard ideas..